# Why am I able to make two borrow variables within the same scope one with mutable reference and the other with immutable reference?

Tags: rust

I just started learning rust. I was following the rust docs. I wrote a program and I am not sure why it works.

According to borrow rules, either I can have one mutable reference in a scope or any number of mutable reference but never both.

So, I cannot have a mutable reference and another immutable reference in the same scope.

But, my program works.

Here is my code -

```
fn main() {
    let s = String::from("Hi");

    let mut s = random(s);
    change_string(&mut s);

    print(&s);

    let d = &mut s;
    change_string(d);

    let f = &s;

    print(f);
    //  print(d);
    //  change_string(d);
}

fn random(mut s: String) -> String {
    s.push_str("rando");
    print(&s);
    s
}

fn change_string(s: &mut String) {
    s.push_str("Hello");
}

fn print(s: &String) {
    println!("{s}");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exactly right that you can't have a mutable and immutable borrow simultaneously. In fact, if you uncomment the two commented lines of code, you'll see that Rust will point this out.

However, Rust is terribly clever.

```
let d = &mut s;
change_string(d);

let f = &s;

print(f);
```

On the `let f = &s` line, Rust *should* fail this code immediately. That's an immutable borrow and we've got a mutable borrow in scope. However, Rust will try to help you. The compiler is smart enough to realize: Okay, we can't have `f` and also keep `d` at the same time. Since `d` is *never* used again, we can just pretend it went out of scope and everything will be fine.

So Rust will effectively insert a `drop(d)` just before the declaration of `f`, since it sees that the variable is never used again. It can't do that if the variable actually *is* used again, so you get an error in that case. The compiler is just trying to be incredibly helpful.